# UDP sockets in C not working

Tags: c, sockets

I am just trying to make a UDP connection for the first time using C on linux.  I have a server which is transmitting a number every second and I have a program which is receiving.  The transmitter seems to be wroking but the receiver does not seem to be getting the messages.  It just blocks on the recv function call.

Sender

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    int sfd, i;

    sfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    bzero(&addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
    addr.sin_port = htons(32000);

    for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        char buffer[100] = { 0 };
        sprintf(buffer, "%d", i);
        puts(buffer);
        if(sendto(sfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1)
        {
            perror("Send");
            exit(1);
        }
        sleep(1);
    }

    close(sfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Receiver

```
int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    int sfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    perror("Socket");

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    addr.sin_port = htons(4000);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
    char buffer[1000];
    int n;

    if(bind(sfd, &addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0)
    {
            perror("Bind");
            exit(1);
    }

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Recv\n");
        n = recv(sfd, buffer, 1000, 0);
        printf("%d\n", n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sender:

```
addr.sin_port = htons(32000);
```

Receiver:

```
addr.sin_port = htons(4000);
```

The port you send to has to be the port you receive on.

Comment: I feel stupid.  I changed the port when I was trying something and I forgot to change it back.